# How do I verify that my proguard rules have been applied to my expo project?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, proguard, eas

I have a simple React native app which I want to submit to Google Play Store via EAS Build. Eas build created .apk file from my react native project. Before that, I want to apply some Proguard rules to protect the code.
I have created the build (in dev mode) and hence I have the .apk file. Now I want to verify that my proguard rules have been applied, but I don't know how. From the .apk file I managed to get some .class files following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file) but honestly, nothing seems familiar to me, plus it converts to `android` project, while mine is `react native`. Any ideas how to verify that my proguard rules have been applied?